# Does atom.io have a read-only mode?

Tags: atom-editor

I am reading a project and would like to set it to read mode.  That is, not be able to edit the file.  Is this possible?  If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported at the moment. Feel free to suggest it as a feature or think about adding this functionality as a package.

Source: https://discuss.atom.io/t/read-only-editor/11125